# How to expire keys starting with a pattern in Redis?

Tags: redis

Given that I have KEY VALUEs stored in Redis and wish to expire keys starting with a pattern.

For example have stored:

```
SET hello.world "Hello"
SET there.how "There"
SET hello.are.you "Are you"
```

Then after the keys were set, want to expire all keys starting with "hello".
Assuming there are really a large number of keys, not just this simple example. Do not wish to do many round trip calls to Redis.

Comment: Do you mean delete all these keys or set EXPIRE for these keys?

Comment: Set expire for these keys

Comment: Cluster or single shard?

Comment: Anyway, you might want to check the RedisGears module for Redis. It allows you to scan all keys according to some prefix and then act on these keys.

Answer (score 1):

I think easiest way is just iterate all the keys with `scan(pattern)`, and expire the keys with `pipeline`, it will do certain round trips as you say

```py
def while_true_loop():
    target_pattern = 'hello.([A-Za-z0-9]*)$'
    simple_pattern = 'hello.*'
    import re
    cursor = 0
    while True:
        cursor, keys = rs.scan(cursor, match=simple_pattern, count=1000)
        pipe = rs.pipeline()
        for key in keys:
            if re.match(target_pattern, key):
                pipe.expire(key, 3600)
        pipe.execute()
        if not keys:
            break
```